# Can anyone explain the error message "Rank-deficient equality constraint subproblem HFTI" from scipy miminize?

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to make sense of the scipy function scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp and came across the error: **Rank-deficient equality constraint subproblem HFTI**.

The error can be found in this official document from [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp.html).

Can anyone explain what is going on with this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try tracing through the source: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/slsqp.py

In general, I would interpret "rank deficient" as "you don't have enough constraints, or some of your constraints are not linearly independent (and therefore disappear after reduction)".

Comment: well, in my use case, i ran into this error when I am using the constraint where the l2 norm of a vector constraint is zero. This is one constraint passed to scipy. I dont see how this can be rank deficient.